# HTML Tags appearing on text in Drupal CKEditor

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-6, tags, ckeditor

Some pages on my Drupal site are showing the HTML tags on the live page.

I'm using CKEditor for this.

This is an example [here](http://www.ifpsm.org/directory/norpo)

Check out the "Activities" section on this page.

Can anyone let me know what's the issue here and why are these tags appearing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you include Html tags while not on View Source mode on CKEditor, it will escape those tags for you. Go into View Source mode and check if those the tags that are showing up are already escaped and then convert them back to Html.

Comment: I'm not using any HTML tags on CKEditor. It's automatically converting the text into HTML tags.

Comment: Here's the source of the text on the live page.

 `<div class="field-item odd">
                    &lt;p&gt;
 a) website;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
 b) online course The Competence Center&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
 c) Workshops&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
 d) Training&lt;/p&gt;
        </div>`

Comment: There's your problem, the tags showing up are already escaped. Just swap that code in View Source mode for: <div class="field-item odd"> <p> a) website;</p> <p> b) online course The Competence Center</p> <p> c) Workshops</p> <p> d) Training</p> </div>

Comment: If you need to decode any other parts with encoded special entities, just decode them here: http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities/

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that I'm not adding those &gt; and &lt; codes to the source code in CKEditor and neither are they showing up in CKEditor Source Viewer when I'm editing the page. The browser is turning these < and > to &lt; and &gt; respectively.